# Having difficulty pointing Selenium towards the right iFrame [python]

Tags: python, selenium, mechanicalturk

I'm trying to get my selenium script to download an image from an MTurk HIT.  My script is able to log into MTurk, go to the "accept a new HIT" page for the HIT I want to grab the image from, but then I'm unable to point it towards the specific image I want.  I've tried every method listed in the selenium documentation `(find_element_by_class_name, by_id, by_element)`, etc, and I'm not able to figure it out.

What I have so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get("https://www.mturk.com/mturk/myhits")

elem = driver.find_element_by_id("ap_email")
elem.send_keys('####')
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("ap_password")
elem.send_keys('###')
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("signInSubmit-input")
elem.click()
driver.get("https://www.mturk.com/mturk/previewandaccept?groupId=3ZXRRTK2NDCB5NW5M24C9P2OWG41OF")
hit = driver.switch_to_frame("ExternalQuestionIFrame")
print(hit)
```

Output this gives me:

```
None
```

Output I'd expect:
The HTML within the link `https://backend.ibotta.com/receipt_moderation/50730299/edit?assignmentId=33FBRBDW6OZTOIJ53FZR716JLOQC8N&hitId=3D3B8GE892RAASDPNAMA2D4I3E3P9G&workerId=A1DY4DM16TBFPL&turkSubmitTo=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mturk.com`

The element I'm trying to reach is referred to in the page source as `ExternalQuestionIFrame`, as you can see below:

```
 </style><iframe height="1000" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0" align="center" src="https://backend.ibotta.com/receipt_moderation/50730299/edit?assignmentId=33FBRBDW6OZTOIJ53FZR716JLOQC8N&amp;hitId=3D3B8GE892RAASDPNAMA2D4I3E3P9G&amp;workerId=A1DY4DM16TBFPL&amp;turkSubmitTo=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mturk.com" name="ExternalQuestionIFrame"></iframe>
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?  Any responses are much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to switch to the iframe to get it's `src`. Just locate the element and use `get_attribute()` to retrieve the `src` attribute value:

```
frame = driver.find_element_by_name("ExternalQuestionIFrame")
print(frame.get_attribute("src"))
```